# Rails is not using password provided in database.yml

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem connecting to DB from my rails app.

I have provided the database.yml file with credentials:

```
development: &development
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: myapp_dev
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: passoword

test:
  <<: *development
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *development
  database: myapp_prod

staging:
  <<: *development
  database: myapp_staging
```

But when I try run the app it gives me the following error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

using `mysql -u root -p` with same credentials I can access my db without issues. can someone tell me what could be a problem here?

**EDIT:**

I've changed the user from root to some other user but it still gives me the same error. so apparently it uses some other credentials to connect to db.

Comment: have you checked that your mysql server is running well or not? if you check that it is running then just try mysql -u root if you able to get into mysql console then your password is not set on mysql so in database.yml you can use only username: root no required pasword

Comment: I have already indicated that I can connect to my db with the credentials using mysql client. and yes it restricts access without password

Comment: Check the password written in database.yml. Is it a typo or your password is passoword?

Comment: I think at least a little debugging should go on before posting to stack overflow. Such as checking for typos..

Comment: Have you restart your server after modifying the database.yml???

Comment: There is no password typo, when the password is wrong MySQL reports an error like this: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`, the chunk `(using password: NO)` means that **no passoword is provided** for authentication.

Comment: Please guys, I wouldn't have posted the question if I haven't checked for typos or restarted the server. besides, as @toro2k said it can't be a typo because the it doesn't use the password at all.

Comment: Check the permissions on the database and tables.

Comment: Just a guess:  Can you use some other anchor instead of &development?

Comment: @WandMaker Changed the anchor, same result.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. It turns out it was a mistake in my `database.yml` file. Here is what my `database.yml` file looked like:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_db
  username: my_db_user
  password: !strong_password
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

The `!` character at the beginning of the password is not valid YAML markup (for at least what I was trying to achieve). Wrapping quotes (`''`) around the password fixes the issue. Here is the updated `database.yml` file:

```
 production:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      database: my_db
      username: my_db_user
      password: '!strong_password'
      host: localhost
      port: 3306
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, if it works we can go forward
Comment all the previous code in database.yml and paste the following

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myapp_dev
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: passoword
  host: localhost
```